# Wired USB mouse left button stops working

Tags: windows-vista, mouse

My wired USB mouse's left button stops working properly after being plugged into the computer for about five minutes. The mouse button will become sticky and not allow me to select things or the left button is completely unresponsive. The mouse driver is up to date.

I am running Windows Vista Home Premium with the Service Pack 2 on a Sony Viao laptop (Model number (VGN-NW125J).

If anybody knows how to fix this your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the drivers. Also, check to see if the mouse works on other computers. See if another mouse works on your computer. These are things that you can try to help figure out where the problem is (driver, mouse, computer). Comment back to tell me the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

- Try plugging the mouse to another USB
  port.
- Try it with another computer.
- Try to untangle and straighten the cable.

After those five minutes, can you move the cursor and right-click?
If the answer is yes and the steps above show that the mouse still seems to not work properly, you probably have defective hardware.